# Efficient way to do pandas operation and skip row

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

There must be a simple way to do this, but I'm missing it. First, imagine the situation in Excel:

1. I have a column of percent changes. (assume column A)
2. In the next column (B), I want to create an indexed series that begins at 1000 based on the percent changes. In Excel, I do this by.
   -setting B1 to 1000
   -set B2 to the formula =(1+A2)*B1
   -copy the column down. Simple.

Now, I want to do the same thing with pandas, and the problem is that the following code results in the target array becoming NaN:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_source = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,.05,10), index=range(10), columns=['A'])

df_target = pd.DataFrame(index = df_source.index) 
df_target.loc[0,"A"] = 1000 # initialize target array to start at 1000

df_target["A"] = (1 + df_source) * df_target["A"].shift(1) # How to skip first row?
```

The target array becomes NaN because the first row tries to reference a value "off the dataframe", so the whole column returns NaN.

I realize I could iterate over rows with a loop, skipping the first row, but this is very slow and not practical for the size of datasets or iterations I will be doing.

There must be a way to use pandas/numpy array functions but tell it to *skip the first row in the calculation*. How to do that? I've tried Boolean indexing but can't get it to work, and maybe there is a way to tell Pandas to skip the NaN results... but the best approach seems to be a qualifier that says "apply this code, starting at the second row."

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**

Looks like my problem is deeper than I realized. jezrael's answer below solves the NA problem, but I think I am confused about the pandas logic. The code I give above DOES NOT work because it does not work element-wise. For instance, the trivial example:

```
seriesdf = pd.DataFrame(index = range(10))
seriesdf['A'] = 1
seriesdf['A'].ix[1:] = 1 + seriesdf['A'].shift(1)
```

gives the result

```
   A
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  2
4  2
5  2
6  2
7  2
8  2
9  2
```

not an ascending count as I had assumed. So the question is what is the most efficient way to do this row by row calculation on a pandas dataframe? Speed matters in this application so I would prefer to not interate through rows.

New python programmer here so trying to figure this out. Answers that show me how to learn/figure stuff like this out for myself are very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, and what is your desired output? And the best learn stuff is [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help on this @jezrael. These solutions worked, but pandas .cumprod() turned out to be the easiest solution. Just critical, given the speed of python vs a faster language, to avoid iterating whenever possible. Thank you!

Comment: Super that it works. I think `pandas` is amazing library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can skip first row of column `A` of `df_source` by selection all rows without first by [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ix.html):

```
df_target["A"].ix[1:] = df_source['A'].ix[1:] + 1
print df_target
             A
0  1000.000000
1     0.988898
2     0.986142
3     1.009979
4     1.005165
5     1.101116
6     0.992312
7     0.962890
8     1.051340
9     1.009750
```

Or maybe you think:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_source = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(0,.05,10), index=range(10), columns=['A'])
print df_source
          A
0  0.039965
1  0.060821
2 -0.079238
3 -0.129932
4  0.002196
5 -0.003721
6 -0.008358
7  0.014104
8 -0.022905
9  0.014793

df_target = pd.DataFrame(index = df_source.index) 
#all A set to 1000
df_target["A"] = 1000 # initialize target array to start at 1000
print df_target
      A
0  1000
1  1000
2  1000
3  1000
4  1000
5  1000
6  1000
7  1000
8  1000
9  1000
```

```
df_target["A"] = (1 + df_source["A"].shift(-1))* df_target["A"]
print df_target
             A
0  1060.820882
1   920.761946
2   870.067878
3  1002.195555
4   996.279287
5   991.641909
6  1014.104402
7   977.094961
8  1014.793488
9          NaN
```

EDIT:

Maybe you need [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df_target["B"]  = 2
df_target["C"] = df_target["B"].cumsum()

df_target["D"] = df_target["B"] + df_target.index
print df_target
             A  B   C   D
0  1041.003000  2   2   2
1  1013.817000  2   4   3
2   948.853000  2   6   4
3  1031.692000  2   8   5
4   970.875000  2  10   6
5  1011.095000  2  12   7
6  1053.472000  2  14   8
7   903.765000  2  16   9
8  1010.546000  2  18  10
9     0.010546  2  20  11
```

Comment: And I forget - welcome to `pandas` and `StackOverflow`. You can check [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your problem and in these cases, I usually find it easier to make a list and append it to the existing dataframe. You, of course, could make an Series instance first *and then* do calculations.

```
new_series = [0]*len(df["A"])                 
new_series[0] = 1000                           

for i,k in enumerate(dataframe["A"].ix[1:]):   
    new_series[i] = (1 + k)*new_series[i-1]    

dataframe["B"] = pd.Series(new_series)
```

IIRC, *iloc* is being deprecated in future builds of pandas in favor of *[ix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html)*

After rethinking the problem, you can use **lambda expressions** as elements in your dataframe

```
dataframe["B"] = [lambda row: (1 + dataframe["A"].ix[row])*dataframe["B"].ix[row-1]*len(dataframe["A"])
# Above: initiate "B" with a lambda expression that is as long as "A"

dataframe["B"].ix[0] = 1000
for i,k in enumerate(dataframe["B"].ix[1]):
    dataframe["B"].ix[i] = k(row=i)
```

I am trying to think of a way around using a for loop to this problem but can't manage to figure where to grab a row number from.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your help on this and for the note on iloc being deprecated.