# Iterate over a Pandas dataframe while skipping the first row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data set organized into a Pandas dataframe.

Here's a small example of the data:

```
        x142_2012  x126_2012   x156_2012  x167_2012     x1_2012  x243_2012  
0      690.842629   0.005029   51.600000   5.454545   43.000000  27.700000   
1     4247.485437   5.062739   95.400000  54.655959  100.000000  15.700000   
2     5583.616160        NaN   84.900000  15.228027  100.000000  31.600000   
3             NaN        NaN  100.000000        NaN   59.328910        NaN   
4    39666.369210  34.335120  100.000000  86.434425  100.000000  50.000000   
5     5531.776299        NaN   47.800000  16.937210   37.000000  34.100000   
6    13525.616220  14.674017   97.900000  58.000000   90.875440  10.500000   
7     7465.145864   3.196932   85.417850  29.954302   86.270751  14.872018   
8    14357.411590  12.530952   98.600000  55.800000   99.800000  37.400000   
9     3565.517575   7.142042   99.700000  37.500000  100.000000  10.700000   
10            NaN        NaN   98.100000  74.000000   90.875440        NaN
```

I want to build a bunch of scatterplots which compare the variable x142_2012 with each other variable, individually. Therefore, I want to iterate over the dataframe, while skipping the first entry. I tried this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

for variable in subset[1:]:
    plt.figure()
    scatterplot = sns.regplot(x="x142_2012", y=variable, fit_reg=False, data=subset)
```

but instead of outputting 5 scatterplots (`x/y1, x/y2, x/y3, x/y4, x/y5`), it output 6 scatterplots with the first being `x/x`.

I'm getting around the issue with this:

```
for variable in subset:
    if variable == "x142_2012":
        continue
    plt.figure()
    scatterplot = sns.regplot(x="x142_2012", y=variable, fit_reg=False, data=subset)
```

But I don't find it very elegant. I looked at [Efficient way to do pandas operation and skip row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389922/efficient-way-to-do-pandas-operation-and-skip-row) and tried `for variable in subset[x].idx[1:]` but it gives me `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'idx'`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I have problems understanding how your dataframe looks like. Could you provide a printout of a Dataframe that has the envisioned structure and clearly state how this relates to `x`, `y1` etc.?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm working with a dataset from the World Bank. I've updated the post to include some more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `subset[1:]`, use `subset.columns[1:]`

Answer (score 2):

`subset[1:]` selects all but the first **row**, the resulting DataFrame still has six columns.

What you can do instead is to iterate over the dataframe's columns (and leave out the first):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data
a = np.random.rand(10,6)
a[:,0]= np.arange(10)
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=[l for l in "xabcde"])
#print df

#plot
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    plt.figure()
    scatterplot = sns.regplot(x="x", y=col, fit_reg=False, data=df)

plt.show()
```